# Public Tableau publishes an incorrect graph

Tags: tableau-api

I created the following using [Public Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/s/)

[image]

But when I publish to tableu (see [here](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/ClassfulNetworks/NumbersandSizesofClassfulNetworks)), column A is pushed all the way to the right, i.e.

[image]

Why does this even happen? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the default sort order for `[Class]` is the data source order. To fix that, right click on Class in the Dimensions list and go to "Default Properties" / "Sort...". In that menu, choose "Alphabetic" in the "Sort by" window.