# Tableau, sort Calculated Field by alphabet

Tags: sorting, tableau-api

This is similar to [Public Tableau publishes an incorrect graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332054/public-tableau-publishes-an-incorrect-graph), except I need to sort Calculated field

The public workbook is [here](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/NumericBusinessRatings/BusinessRatings), and sometimes, `Grade` is not sorted, i.e. `A` is at the end (cannot get screenshot at the moment)

When I right click `Grade`, I cannot find option to sort alphabetically and get this instead

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error (for me the grades are sorted).
However if you right click on AGG(Grade) in the column shelf you have a "Sort" option.

[image]

Maybe that's what causes the error?

Comment: I didn't realize the option to sort once data is on the rows/columns shelf. Thanks!